# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call")

Tags: magento, soap

I'm using SOAP API to print the product information using it's SKU in Magento. Code is working fine on local server but it's throws fatal error on live server **Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call") is not a valid method for this service....**

```
//require_once("../app/Mage.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$mage_url = 'http://mylivedomain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl' ;
$mage_user = 'username'; 
$mage_api_key = 'password'; 
// Initialize the SOAP client 
$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 
// Login to Magento 
$session_id = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );
$resources = $soap->resources( $session_id );
$product = $soap->call( $session_id, 'catalog_product.info', ergo10000012 );
print_r ($product);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becuase the SOAP version and the web-service call methods are mismatching...

The URL should be : $mage_url = 'http://mylivedomain.com/api/soap/?wsdl' ;